# Is my model overparameterized? Considering regularization but unsure how to keep some significance score (or if I even should)

Tags: regression, regularization, overfitting, statsmodels

I have trained a model on some sales data, we have separated the data into different groups of customers based on the marketing strategies of our client.  We have a total of 10 groups and 31 coupons.  So I trained a linear regression with client group as a factor with 10 levels and each coupon having two (assigned or unassigned), plus interactions between coupons and customer group so a total of 63 parameters (64 including the intercept).  I also trained a model without the customer groups.  Without the customer groups the r-squared is 0.19, including the customer groups parameter in the model without interactions gives a much better r-squared 0.27 and then the model with interactions gives a moderate increase to 0.283 but this model has a fairly low f-test.  The first two had f-tests in the 400's.  The model with the interactions has an f-test in the 70's...  Not sure what to make of this, thinking of calculating the predicted R-squared using k-fold crossvalidation.  Other regression metrics look good, (healthy QQ-plots no sign of heteroskedacity etc etc).

My question is is this drop in significance a sign of overfitting?  If so I can regularize but then I'm not sure how to get a significance score I've read bootstrapping significances for regularized effects is challenging.  Also won't the L1 and L2 norms make my effect sizes less interpretable?

Here are the model summaries, from statsmodels .summary(), I have skipped the first model.

**Model with customer groups but no intercepts :**

[image]

**Full model :**

[image]